# How to send a transaction to Aptos using Petra Wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallet, aptos

This is the code I am testing which I got from [petra docs](https://petra.app/docs/sending-a-transaction).

```js
const wallet = getAptosWallet(); // see "Connecting"

// Example Transaction, following an [EntryFunctionPayload](https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/blob/main/ecosystem/typescript/sdk/src/generated/models/EntryFunctionPayload.ts#L8-L21)
const transaction = {
  arguments: [address, '717'],
  function: '0x1::coin::transfer',
  type: 'entry_function_payload',
  type_arguments: ['0x1::aptos_coin::TestCoin'],
};

try {
  const pendingTransaction = await(
    window as any,
  ).aptos.signAndSubmitTransaction(transaction);

  // In most cases a dApp will want to wait for the transaction, in these cases you can use the typescript sdk
  const client = new AptosClient('https://testnet.aptoslabs.com');
  const txn = await client.waitForTransactionWithResult(
    pendingTransaction.hash,
  );
} catch (error) {
  // see "Errors"
}
```

I expected it work without any error since i got it from docs, but I am wrong. I only added the address in arguments.

The error which I am seeing is

```
Transaction error
TYPE_RESOLUTION_FAILURE
```

What is cauing this error and How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the problem is `0x1::aptos_coin::TestCoin`. It is failing to resolve that type because that type doesn't exist on testnet, see `aptos_coin` here: https://explorer.aptoslabs.com/account/0x1/modules. Instead you want `0x1::aptos_coin::AptosCoin`.

I see that your code came from these docs here: https://petra.app/docs/sending-a-transaction. I'll chat with the team to get these updated, `0x1::aptos_coin::TestCoin` was removed a long time ago.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Using AptosCoin works. Works perfectly. 

And Thanks for the reference docs.